# Set Focus on textbox when starting webpage

Tags: setfocus

When the webpage loads the focus is on the URL and not on the text box.

Code used:
On Page load:
`TextBox1.Focus();` and `SetFocus(TextBox1);` - Neither work

On asp side on tried in content:
defaultfocus="TextBox1"

and `OnLoad="Focus_Textbox"`
calling function

```
protected void Focus_Textbox(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextBox1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Code I have used:

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" onload = "Focus_Textbox">

protected void Focus_Textbox(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        TextBox1.Focus(); 
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
Focus_Textbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   TextBox1.SetFocus;
}
```

I think this works fine with .Net 4.0..